# Getting issue with file permissions in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, apache2, php, chmod, web-development

I've a development desktop having Ubuntu 10.04, Apache2 & PHP 5.3.2 installed. I've given 0777 permissions to my web application root folder and Apache2 is also running under current username. But *sometimes* following files error is getting,

> file_put_contents(/var/www/kohana_project/application/cache/kohana_find_file_paths):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied.

For every request above file need to update and execute but error occurs rarely. Is any one have idea how to fix this issue ?

And one thing current logged-in user and www-data have full permissions on kohana_project directory and its contents.

Answer (score 1):

the possible reason would be that you've not changed the **owner** of the file, though you've changed the **permissions**. :)

So first you've to get the owner name under which **apache** server is running, and assign the same owner to you `/var/www/<file/folder>`.

Follow these steps:

1. find the owner of the **httpd**. Execute this command to get the owner of **httpd**:

   ```
   sudo ps aux | grep httpd
   ```

   the first column will be the owner say **somebody**. If you get number like **1001** or any other number instead of **somebody** then execute this command to get the owner name:

   ```
   grep 1001 /etc/passwd
   ```

   Again the first field will be the owner of the process.
2. Now change the owner of file/folder under **www** to **somebody**

   ```
   sudo chown -R somebody /var/www/<path to the file/folder>
   ```
3. Restart your server

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

That's it. Hope it would help you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've did how you have suggested, but after executing application files ownership in `cache` folders are changing to `www-data`, anyhow +1 for reasonable answer.